# Getting error during "truffle migrate" for an ethereum contract on testrpc

Tags: ethereum, truffle

While trying out the ethereum contract mentioned at the tutorial: https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/a-101-noob-intro-to-programming-smart-contracts-on-ethereum-695d15c1dab4#.ilmaiavg0 (source code for the tutorial: https://github.com/eshon/conference), I get the following error while doing truffle migrate:

```
test@test-ubuntu:~/Blockchain/Ethereum/conference$ truffle migrate
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Server error
    at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
    at [object Object].request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:114:13)
    at [object Object].dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:396:17)
```

testrpc is up and running, and I see following two lines in testrpc terminal when I run truffle migrate:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-10-21 09:38:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.001741
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-10-21 09:38:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 493 0.042596
```

Am I missing anything in the configuration?
My Source Code is at https://github.com/manindra23/conference-contract/tree/develop

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try to give network setup in truffle.js file

like this,

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    }
  }
```